# The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, singleton

I'm trying out some code from a [singleton base class article](http://codebender.denniland.com/a-singleton-base-class-to-implement-the-singleton-pattern-in-c/). But when I compile, it's giving me that error message. I made sure the project's target framework is 4.0 full, not 4.0 client framework. What's wrong with the code?

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public abstract class SingletonBase<t> where T : class
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// A protected constructor which is accessible only to the sub classes.
        /// </summary>
        protected SingletonBase() { }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the singleton instance of this class.
        /// </summary>
        public static T Instance
        {
            get { return SingletonFactory.Instance; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The singleton class factory to create the singleton instance.
        /// </summary>
        class SingletonFactory
        {
            // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
            // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
            static SingletonFactory() { }

            // Prevent the compiler from generating a default constructor.
            SingletonFactory() { }

            internal static readonly T Instance = GetInstance();

            static T GetInstance()
            {
                var theType = typeof(T);

                T inst;

                try
                {
                    inst = (T)theType
                      .InvokeMember(theType.Name,
                        BindingFlags.CreateInstance | BindingFlags.Instance
                        | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                        null, null, null,
                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                }
                catch (MissingMethodException ex)
                {
                    throw new TypeLoadException(string.Format(
                      CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                      "The type '{0}' must have a private constructor to " +
                      "be used in the Singleton pattern.", theType.FullName)
                      , ex);
                }

                return inst;
            }
        }
    }

    public sealed class SequenceGeneratorSingleton : SingletonBase<SequenceGeneratorSingleton>
    {
        // Must have a private constructor so no instance can be created externally.
        SequenceGeneratorSingleton()
        {
            _number = 0;
        }

        private int _number;

        public int GetSequenceNumber()
        {
            return _number++;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sequence: " + SequenceGeneratorSingleton.Instance
                .GetSequenceNumber().ToString());  // Print "Sequence: 0"

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it the case of `t`? It should be `T`. At any rate, it needs to be consistent throughout your class, and upper-case is the convention.

Answer (score 1):

```
public abstract class SingletonBase<t> where T : class
```

Should be:

```
public abstract class SingletonBase<T> where T : class
```

C# is case sensitive so the compiler saw `where T : class` as referring to an unknown generic type parameter since you used a lowercase t in the type delcaration, `SingletonBase<t>`.